# Regular expression to replace all occurrences of U.S

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a regular expression to replace all occurrences of U.S. . Here's what I thought would work.

```
string = re.sub(r'\bU.S.\b', 'U S ', string)
```

When I run this it only finds the first occurrence. Why is this and how can I resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: I thought the r caused it to repeat. Sorry

Comment: `r` means a raw string.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'll reread the doc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.` has special meaning in regular expressions (it matches any character), so it needs to be escaped.

```
string = re.sub(r'\bU\.S\.', 'U S ', string)
```

Also, you shouldn't use `\b` after `.`. `\b` matches between a word and non-word character. Since `.` is a non-word character, it will only match if the `.` is followed by a word character, e.g. `U.S.foo`, but not `U.S. currency` because the `.` is followed by space, which isn't a word character.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ZPtTDc)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the clarification. Still trying to rap my head around regx.

Comment: Cool Thanks I'll check that out. I just retested and for some reason It's still only getting the first occurrence.

Comment: Maby there's something else going on with my code that messing this up. I'll  have to dig a bit deeper.

Comment: I just updated my demo to have multiple occurrences and it works. Maybe you should update the question to show the initial value of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are searching in a file, to find all occurrences and replace them, you need to search line by line.

the . need to be \. because . itself has other meanings in RE.
A safer way to implement is to write \b+ so it counts for 1 or more such cases.

r doesnt mean repeat, it means escape character wont be processed

by the way, you dont need to worry \b after the . because the RE will match everything before that, and ignore what is not matching. You are indeed getting the first part printed first time while you have the wrong RE, right?